# Unable to retrieve first and last valid index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am working with streamflow data loaded into pandas from .csv files. I need to extract the dates of first and last valid entries of streamflow values.I am trying to get the index of first and last valid (non NaN) streamflow values and then use `pd.at[]` function. I am using :

`pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index` and `pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index`.

However, the above functions are not able to return the index for some files and gives output = `none` . Moreover, the range index and its type is same for all the files. Please check the example below :

```
station2 = pd.read_csv('../flow/IWM-gauge-0002.csv')
station4 = pd.read_csv('../flow/IWM-gauge-0004.csv')
print('Station 2 index type :',type(station2.index))
print('Station 4 index type :',type(station4.index))
print('Station 2 index : ',station2.index)
print('Station 4 index :',station4.index)
```

Running the above code gives output as :

```
Station 2 index type : <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'>
Station 4 index type : <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'>
Station 2 index :  RangeIndex(start=0, stop=22333, step=1)
Station 4 index : RangeIndex(start=0, stop=22333, step=1)
```

However, If I try to retrieve first or last valid index for both dataframes :

```
first_validx_2 = station2['Streamflow (cumecs)'].first_valid_index()
first_validx_4 = station4['Streamflow (cumecs)'].first_valid_index()
last_validx_2 = station2['Streamflow (cumecs)'].last_valid_index()
last_validx_4 = station4['Streamflow (cumecs)'].last_valid_index()

print('First valid idx in station 2',first_validx_2)
print('First valid idx in station 4',first_validx_4)
print('Last valid idx in station 2',last_validx_2)
print('Last valid idx in station 4',last_validx_4)
```

I get the following output :

```
First valid idx in station 2 19780
First valid idx in station 4 None
Last valid idx in station 2 21885
Last valid idx in station 4 None
```

Please guide where am I going wrong? How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Is it possible that all the values of **station 4** are not valid for the ```Streamflow (cumecs)``` data series?

Comment: Ah!! You were right. There is no valid value in entire series. I never thought of that. Thank you.

Comment: Happy that it helped! Good luck with your project!